# how i can auth in laravel with to models hasone

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

```
Person
    id - integer
    dni - string
    name - string
User
    id-interger
    id_person integer
    password-string
```

i have this two tables, and i need authenticate with dni from Person and password from user

i tried adding

```
  public function username()
    {
        return 'dni';
    }
```

in Auth/LoginController, but not working
In my config/auth.php :

```
'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
```

how can I still authenticate with two different table fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$person = Person::where('dni', $dni)->first();

if (Auth::attempt(['id_person' => $person->id, 'password' => $password])) {

     // Authentication passed...
}
```